# Is there anyway to increase 'App Storage' space on a HTC One X?

Tags: internal-storage, htc-one-x

I'm currently using 6.48GB of 6.76GB 'App storage' on my HTC One X of which 4.95GB is classed as 'other'.

I've seen some guides which suggest methods to extend storage onto an SD card but the HTC One X doesn't have a slot for one.

Is there any way to repartition or something along those lines? Or is it time to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :
[How I expanded my app storage (repartitioning)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1388996)

or developing a rom with your requirement.

(*delete the unused or etc **apps/files** from rom*)